# Big fractions for exponentials

Tags: math-mode

Does anybody know how to represent this style of fraction?
Notice that it is located inside an exponential.

[image]

Comment: It's just `$v_{k}(t) = e^{j(2\pi/T_{0})kt}$` by the looks of it: did you try simply typing in the appropriate math mode material? (I note you asked an earlier very simple math mode question: have you studied a basic beginners guide to LaTeX?)

Comment: I put it in \begin{equation}..\end{equation} block..

Comment: @john john: If you're having trouble with questions like these, you should take a look at [Web Equation](http://webdemo.visionobjects.com/home.html#equation): write the equation on the screen and it will show you how it's written in LaTeX and what that LaTeX output will be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Joseph wrote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153486/big-fractions-for-exponentials/153488#comment350579_153486), just use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  v_{k}(t)
  = e^{j(2\pi/T_{0})kt}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]